Why is flutter attach not working in the following setup using vscode docker devcontainer and adb running on host?
I have adb installed on windwos host, java, android sdk, flutter and adb installed in docker container. The adb server runs on host using the following command:
adb -a nodaemon server start
Flutter build works, flutter install works, flutter run works up until debugger should connect, flutter attach doesnt work.
My problem is the atatch part, I cant attach a debugger to the device. Logs below.
My devcontainer.json is the following:
{
   "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "options": [
            "--progress=plain"
        ]
    },
    "privileged": true,
    "runArgs": [
        "--network=host",
        "--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ]
}

Dockerfile is mainly installing flutter, jdk, android sdk, etc but I only set some env vars that might be relevant:
# Use dart stable as base

# Set up environment variables for Flutter and Android SDK
ENV JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/android-sdk"
ENV ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_ADDRESS="host.docker.internal"
ENV FLUTTER_HOME="/flutter"
ENV FLUTTER_VERSION="3.22.2"
ENV PATH="${FLUTTER_HOME}/bin:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/platform-tools:${PATH}"

The project could be the initial flutter project for example.
Relevant error log:
[        ] BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
[        ] 41 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 37 up-to-date
[        ] Some of the file system contents retained in the virtual file system are on file systems that Gradle doesn't support watching. The relevant state was discarded to ensure changes to these locations are properly detected. You can override this by explicitly enabling file system watching.
[ +329 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 2,483ms)
[   +1 ms] Calculate SHA1: LocalDirectory: '/workspaces/app_name/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk'/app-debug.apk
[+1743 ms] ✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk
[   +5 ms] executing: /android-sdk/build-tools/33.0.0/aapt dump xmltree /workspaces/app_name/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +7 ms] Exit code 0 from: /android-sdk/build-tools/33.0.0/aapt dump xmltree /workspaces/app_name/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[        ] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x22
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="14" (Raw: "14")
               A: package="com.example.app_name" (Raw: "com.example.app_name")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x22
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xe
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x15
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x22
               E: uses-permission (line=15)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: queries (line=23)
                 E: intent (line=24)
                   E: action (line=25)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" (Raw: "android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT")
                   E: data (line=27)
                     A: android:mimeType(0x01010026)="text/plain" (Raw: "text/plain")
               E: application (line=31)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="app_name" (Raw: "app_name")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.app.Application" (Raw: "android.app.Application")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=37)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.app_name.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.example.app_name.MainActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=52)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" (Raw: "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                   E: intent-filter (line=56)
                     E: action (line=57)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=59)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=66)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
                 E: uses-library (line=70)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.window.extensions" (Raw: "androidx.window.extensions")
                   A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: uses-library (line=73)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.window.sidecar" (Raw: "androidx.window.sidecar")
                   A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
[   +2 ms] Stopping app 'app-debug.apk' on SM S906B.
[        ] executing: /android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.50.35:5555 shell am force-stop com.example.app_name
[ +166 ms] executing: /android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.50.35:5555 shell pm list packages com.example.app_name
[  +70 ms] 
           Exception occurred while executing 'list':
           java.lang.SecurityException: Shell does not have permission to access user 150
            com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser:15970 android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser:5152 com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId:3733 
            at com.android.server.am.UserController.handleIncomingUser(UserController.java:2892)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:15970)
            at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:5152)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:3733)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runListPackages(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1074)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runListPackages(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:960)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runList(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:800)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:237)
            at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
            at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:7119)
            at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1104)
            at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:914)
            at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4905)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:7103)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1380)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1311)
[   +2 ms] ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 255:

           Exception occurred while executing 'list':
           java.lang.SecurityException: Shell does not have permission to access user 150
            com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser:15970 android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser:5152 com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId:3733 
            at com.android.server.am.UserController.handleIncomingUser(UserController.java:2892)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:15970)
            at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:5152)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.translateUserId(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:3733)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runListPackages(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1074)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runListPackages(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:960)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runList(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:800)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:237)
            at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
            at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:7119)
            at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1104)
            at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:914)
            at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4905)
            at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:7103)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1380)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1311)
             Command: /android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.50.35:5555 shell pm list packages com.example.app_name
[        ] Installing APK.
[   +1 ms] Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk...
[        ] executing: /android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.50.35:5555 install -t -r /workspaces/app_name/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk
[+19645 ms] Performing Streamed Install
            Success
[   +1 ms] Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk... (completed in 19.6s)
[   +1 ms] executing: /android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.50.35:5555 shell echo -n a6d7914d41038931601fc42949ec43d6b787acdb > /data/local/tmp/sky.com.example.app_name.sha1
[  +36 ms] executing: /android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.50.35:5555 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[ +515 ms] --------- beginning of main
           08-13 16:42:55.370 I/Finsky  (  894): [662] lmb.a(220): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > ItemModel > CacheSize=171, cacheHitCount=0, cacheMissCount=0, total appsWithNoServerDataCount=15. Missed  in cache (limit 10) : []
[   +7 ms] executing: /android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.50.35:5555 shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true com.example.app_name/com.example.app_name.MainActivity
[  +89 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.example.app_name/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[        ] Waiting for VM Service port to be available...
[ +440 ms] VM Service URL on device: http://127.0.0.1:44705/_E1WAZWYkl0=/
[        ] executing: /android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 192.168.50.35:5555 forward tcp:0 tcp:44705
[  +16 ms] 64722
[        ] Forwarded host port 64722 to device port 44705 for VM Service
[   +6 ms] Caching compiled dill
[  +65 ms] Connecting to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:64722/_E1WAZWYkl0=/
[  +12 ms] Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 40246
[        ] This was attempt #1. Will retry in 0:00:00.100000.
[ +105 ms] Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 40254
[        ] This was attempt #2. Will retry in 0:00:00.200000.
[ +201 ms] Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 40258
[        ] This was attempt #3. Will retry in 0:00:00.400000.
[ +404 ms] Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 40262
[        ] This was attempt #4. Will retry in 0:00:00.800000.
[ +804 ms] Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 40272
[        ] This was attempt #5. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000.
[+1601 ms] Exception attempting to connect to the VM Service: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 40288
[        ] This was attempt #6. Will retry in 0:00:01.600000.


In the dev container, flutter dev

Not a real solution, but if I just use this in runArgs:
     "--network=host"

and remove this form runArgs:
 "--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

and also remove this from Dockerfile:
ENV ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_ADDRESS="host.docker.internal"
And I connect to phone via tcp, it works.
